# What is the reason that animation is so slow with AnimationFrame?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm learning Javascript and canvas animation. Trying to do something with animation for upgrade my skills, this time it's simple slot machine.

It would be great if  somebody could explain me why is this "machine" is so slow? What I'm doing wrong?

I'm trying to use requestAnimationFrame instead of SetInterval.

And the last, for somebodie's of you are my code could be awful, but remember that I'm just learning :)

```
function main(){ // This is the main function 

canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = WIDTH;
canvas.height = HEIGTH;
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

init();
canvas.addEventListener('click', function(){
    // update();
    // window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
    // setInterval(update, 100);
    update();
});
};

main();

function imgLoad(imgArray){
    var Images = [];
    imgArray.forEach(function(link){
        img = new Image();
        img.src = link;
        Images.push(img);
    });

    return Images;

};
function Reel(x ,y){  // This is my constructor with drawImage method
    var _this = this;
    _this.x = x;
    _this.y = y;
    _this.vel = 5;
    _this.counter = 20;

    this.changeY = function(){
        _this.y += _this.vel;
    };
    this.draw = function(){   // this function draws rows with images

    imgLoad(imgArray);

    img.addEventListener('load', function(){
        for(var i = 0; i < imgLoad(imgArray).length; i+=1){

        ctx.drawImage(imgLoad(imgArray)[i], _this.x, _this.y + i * canvas.height / 4, canvas.width / 5, canvas.height / 4);
        }
    });

};
function makeReels(){  // making the instances of Reel constructor

    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i+=1){
        reels.push(new Reel(canvas.width / 5 * i, 0));
    }
};
function init(){  // drawing first images
    makeReels();

    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i+=1){
        reels[i].draw();
    };
};
function update(){  // this is my update function the I'm redrawing images with new Y position

    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i+=1){

        (function(i){
        setTimeout(function(){
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

        reels[i].changeY();
        reels[i].draw();
            }, 100 * i);
        })(i);
        };
        reels[0].counter --;

        if(reels[0].counter > 0){
            window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
        }
        else {
            window.cancelAnimationFrame(update);
            reels[0].counter = 20;

        }
    };
```

Comment: slow is very vague, could you provide a working example?

Comment: @DarthJS I recommend you take time to read this http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/ I used it and had no problems with animations.

Comment: @vitr  Yes, I know it. I've tried to put it into the Jsfiddle, but it's doesn't work
 [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Ldso8sac/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've condensed your code down a bit and this is what I see:

```
function update(){
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i+=1){
        //calculate stuff
        //draw stuff
        window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }
}
```

It looks like for each time you call update(), you call it 5 more times, then each one of those will call update() 5 times. The number of calls to update will increase exponentially. I suspect this is the reason for your slow animation.

I recommend only using requestAnimationFrame() for drawing stuff, keep calculations and variable manipulation outside.

**Example**

```
function myDrawFunction() {
    //Draw stuff here
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function myUpdateFunction () {
    //Here we will be more strict about when stuff are being updated.
    //i.e. here we care about the elapsed time since last update
}
```

Comment: I've already resolve it, but any way thanks a lot for your example and recommendation, I'll remember it. Thanks